# How to convert three columns into pandas datetime?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading my logs like this

```
d = [line.rstrip() for line in open('ufw.txt').readlines()]
```

Once I have a list,I am reading it into Pandas df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([i.split(" ") for i in d])

    0   1         2             3        4  5   ...         22         23            24        25   26      27
0  Aug  14  10:57:53  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=57846   DPT=6443  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0
1  Aug  14  10:58:12  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=60154  DPT=10250  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0
2  Aug  14  10:58:34  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=53386  DPT=10250  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0
3  Aug  14  10:58:57  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=34210  DPT=10250  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0
4  Aug  14  10:59:12  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=49134  DPT=10250  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0
5  Aug  14  10:59:34  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=52082  DPT=10250  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0
6  Aug  14  10:59:52  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=54094   DPT=6443  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0
7  Aug  14  11:00:12  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=35966  DPT=10250  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0
8  Aug  14  11:00:34  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=40132  DPT=10250  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0
```

What I really want is to convert the first three columns into the single datetime column  and leave the rest.
How to achieve that?

Comment: What is the year of your date? Please provide the input file and the exact expected output

Comment: @mozway These are logs from my server,without year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Aug', '14', '10:57:53', 'mjbc-IdeaPad', 'kernel:', '...'],
        ['Aug', '14', '10:58:12', 'mjbc-IdeaPad', 'kernel:', '...']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['datetime'] = df[0] + ' ' + df[1] + ' ' + df[2]

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%b %d %H:%M:%S')

df.drop([0, 1, 2], axis=1, inplace=True)

df = df[['datetime'] + [col for col in df if col != 'datetime']]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
(df.assign(**{'0': 
    pd.to_datetime(
        '2023' + ' ' +df['0']+' ' + df['1'].astype(str) +' ' +df['2'])})
 .drop(['1', '2'], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
                    0             3        4  5  ...         22         23  \
0 2023-08-14 10:57:53  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=57846   DPT=6443   
1 2023-08-14 10:58:12  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=60154  DPT=10250   
2 2023-08-14 10:58:34  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=53386  DPT=10250   
3 2023-08-14 10:58:57  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=34210  DPT=10250   
4 2023-08-14 10:59:12  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=49134  DPT=10250   
5 2023-08-14 10:59:34  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=52082  DPT=10250   
6 2023-08-14 10:59:52  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=54094   DPT=6443   
7 2023-08-14 11:00:12  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=35966  DPT=10250   
8 2023-08-14 11:00:34  mjbc-IdeaPad  kernel:  [  ...  SPT=40132  DPT=10250   

             24        25   26      27  
0  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0  
1  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0  
2  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0  
3  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0  
4  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0  
5  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0  
6  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0  
7  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0  
8  WINDOW=64860  RES=0x00  SYN  URGP=0
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible, it might be better to read the file as csv.

If you really want to use a loop one option is to slice:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[' '.join((l:=i.split(" "))[:2])]+l[2:] for i in d])

df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
```